# How to execute multiple case when statements for each iteration in SAS?

Tags: sql, sas, runtime

I'm using proc sql, and using multiple case when statements to add columns with either a 0 or 1 if the condition is met. It's a big bottleneck right now since it has to scan through each id for each case when statement. So I'm trying to figure out a way to somehow nest the case statements to perform each iteration, instead of having to iterate for all case statements.

This is an example of my code that is taking too long right now.

```
SELECT *,
        CASE WHEN loannumber IN (
            SELECT loannumber FROM PREPAY_LOAN_IDS
        ) THEN 1
        ELSE 0 END AS PREPAY_FLAG,

        CASE WHEN loannumber IN (
            SELECT loannumber FROM DPD_30_IDS
        ) THEN 1    
        ELSE 0 END AS DPD_30_FLAG,

        CASE WHEN loannumber IN (
            SELECT loannumber FROM DPD_60_IDS
        ) THEN 1
        ELSE 0 END AS DPD_60_FLAG,

        CASE WHEN loannumber IN (
            SELECT loannumber FROM DPD_90_IDS
        ) THEN 1    
        ELSE 0 END AS DPD_90_FLAG,

        CASE WHEN loannumber IN (
            SELECT loannumber FROM DPD_120_IDS
        ) THEN 1
        ELSE 0 END AS DPD_120_FLAG,

        CASE WHEN loannumber IN (
            SELECT loannumber FROM FORECLOSURE_IDS
        ) THEN 1    
        ELSE 0 END AS FORECLOSURE_FLAG

FROM(
    SELECT *
    FROM MORTGAGES
    )
```

Comment: Why are you using a subquery in your `FROM` statement instead of just `FROM MORTGAGES`?

Comment: Perhaps it would be faster to `LEFT JOIN` all of the tables on `loannumber` and see if that does it faster.

Comment: Do any of these tables contain duplicate `loannumber` values?

Comment: Yes they do contain duplicate loannumber values. The subquery in the FROM statement was unnecessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below query will work faster than the one you have posted as the input table is not completely access to retrieve the results. Try running this query and see how it performs.

```
SELECT M.*,
        CASE WHEN PLI.loannumber IS NOT NULL THEN 1
        ELSE 0 END AS PREPAY_FLAG,
        CASE WHEN D3I.loannumber IS NOT NULL THEN 1    
        ELSE 0 END AS DPD_30_FLAG,
        CASE WHEN D6I.loannumber IS NOT NULL THEN 1
        ELSE 0 END AS DPD_60_FLAG,
        CASE WHEN D9I.loannumber IS NOT NULL THEN 1    
        ELSE 0 END AS DPD_90_FLAG,
        CASE WHEN D12I.loannumber IS NOT NULL THEN 1
        ELSE 0 END AS DPD_120_FLAG,
        CASE WHEN FCI.loannumber IS NOT NULL THEN 1    
        ELSE 0 END AS FORECLOSURE_FLAG
  FROM MORTGAGES M
 LEFT JOIN 
       PREPAY_LOAN_IDS PLI
    ON M.loannumber = PLI.loannumber
 LEFT JOIN 
      DPD_30_IDS D3I
    ON M.loannumber = D3I.loannumber 
LEFT JOIN 
       DPD_30_IDS D6I
    ON M.loannumber = D6I.loannumber
 LEFT JOIN 
      DPD_90_IDS D9I
    ON M.loannumber = D9I.loannumber
LEFT JOIN 
       DPD_90_IDS D12I
    ON M.loannumber = D12I.loannumber
 LEFT JOIN 
      FORECLOSURE_IDS FCI
    ON M.loannumber = FCI.loannumber
;
```

Comment: If the loannumber is not unique in the other tables, then you'll have duplicate columns.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using SAS, here's a data step alternative, assuming that each of your datasets is already either sorted by or has an index on `loannumber`:

```
data want;
  merge MORTGAGES(in = Mortgages)
        PREPAY_LOAN_IDS(in = PLIDs keep = loannumber)
        /*etc*/
        ;
  by loannumber;
  if Mortgages;
  PREPAY_FLAG = PLIDs;
  /*etc*/
run;
```

N.B. You will get duplicated records from `MORTGAGES` if you have duplicates in any of your other tables.